# Gradle error in ijresolvers.gradle when running using Intellij IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I'm going to run the project directly by Intellij IDEA, it generates this error below.

This `ijresolvers.gradle` is auto generated, so when I try to change it, IDEA creates another one.

The output:

```
18:16:12: Executing 'run'...

:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.251 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/fp/gn6yng6x3sg1k5dx37jy1bnntsymvt/T/ijresolvers.gradle' line: 331

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.whenReady() is applicable for argument types: (SetupUtpTestResultListenerAction) values: [SetupUtpTestResultListenerAction@30600d18]
  Possible solutions: whenReady(groovy.lang.Closure)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.154 secs
18:16:15: Execution finished 'run'.
```

My config:

- MacOS Big Sur
- Intellij IDEA 2021.3
- Java 1.8.202

Comment: Could you provide more information? Which gradle version, what does your gradle configuration look like?

Comment: Looks like incompatibility between Gradle and JDK used. Please specify the JDK and Gradle versions you use. A sample project would be very helpful. Changing Gradle and JDK version could possibly help. You can change them in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | **Gradle** settings.

Comment: Change your Gradle version and try to reopen the project.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in IntelliJ 2021.3. I've created a bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291112

In the meantime, like others already said, downgrading to 2021.2 looks like the only solution right now.

EDIT: This only happens with gradle 3.0 - Upgrading to 3.1 fixes it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with a similar environment (Big Sur, IntelliJ 2021.3, Java 1.8, Gradle 3), and was able to successfully run gradle tasks after downgrading IntelliJ to version 2021.2

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issues with (Big Sur/Monterey, IntelliJ 2021.3, Java 1.8, Gradle 3). I found the solution to be the same as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597547/8454898.
Downgrading to IntelliJ 2021.2.4 worked in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps:

1. Disable the Kotlin plugin (File -> Settings -> Plugins)
2. Invalidate caches (File -> Invalid Caches/Restart)

Worked in my case: Win 11 + IntelliJ 2023.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your IntelliJ Gradle configuration. In IntelliJ, go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart, then Build > Rebuild Project. This will re-synchronize IntelliJ with your Gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

`Gradle run configuration` won't work for this specific IntelliJ IDE, but if you work with Grails framework try `Grails run configuration`. It worked as usual for both: run or debug

[image]